# Метод, ожидающий действие пользователя

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Пишу WPF-приложение на C#. Есть метод, показывающий окошко с сообщением и 2-мя кнопками. Он должен возвращать 0 или 1 (например), в зависимости от нажатой кнопки, как это делает метод `ShowDialog()` класса `Form`. Так вот как собственно это реализовать? Вот примерный макет метода:

```
public int ShowMessage()
    {
        OpenWindow();
        //каким-то образом ожидаем действия пользователя
        //отслеживаем нажатую кнопку
        //и возвращаем соответствующее значение
        return (/* if pressedKey1*/) ? 1 : 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У Влада какой-то сложный способ, я предлагаю сделать всё просто и топорно. По сути, у диалогов по-хорошему должно быть два способа вызова: модальный и немодальный.

- Модальный режим предполагает вызов `ShowModal`, блокировку основного окна и вызывающей функции.
- Немодальный режим предполагает вызов `Show`, доступность основного окна и ожидание с помощью `await`.

Использование будет выглядеть так (давайте числа не возвращать, это дурной тон):

```
private async void ShowPopups ()
{
    Result modalResult = YesNoPopup.ShowPopupModal("Modal");
    // UI блокирован
    MessageBox.Show(modalResult.ToString());

    Result notModalResult = await YesNoPopup.ShowPopup("Not modal");
    // UI не блокирован
    MessageBox.Show(notModalResult.ToString());
}

public enum Result
{
    Yes,
    No,
    Cancel,
}
```

Добавим в класс попапа свойство с результатом вызова, кнопкам назначим соответствующие обработчики.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using static WpfDialogSample.Result;

public class YesNoPopup : Window
{
    private Result? _result;

    public YesNoPopup ()
    {
        Button btnYes, btnNo, btnCancel;
        SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
        WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        Content = new UniformGrid {
            Columns = 3,
            Children = {
                (btnYes = new Button { Content = "Yes" }),
                (btnNo = new Button { Content = "No" }),
                (btnCancel = new Button { Content = "Cancel" }),
            }
        };
        btnYes.Click += (s, a) => SetResult(Yes);
        btnNo.Click += (s, a) => SetResult(No);
        btnCancel.Click += (s, a) => SetResult(Cancel);
    }

    private void SetResult (Result result)
    {
        _result = result;
        Close();
    }

    // ...
}
```

А дальше в пару строчек реализуем модальную и немодальную версию. Здесь считается, что закрытие диалога эквивалентно нажатию на `Cancel`.

```
public class YesNoPopup : Window
{
    // ...

    public static Result ShowPopupModal (string title)
    {
        var popup = new YesNoPopup { Title = title };
        popup.ShowDialog();
        return popup._result ?? Cancel;
    }

    public static async Task<Result> ShowPopup (string title)
    {
        var completion = new TaskCompletionSource<Result?>();
        var popup = new YesNoPopup { Title = title };
        popup.Closed += (s, a) => completion.SetResult(popup._result);
        popup.Show();
        return await completion.Task ?? Cancel;
    }
}
```

Собственно, вот и весь код вместе со всеми элементами управления.

Comment: Что такое и как добавить `static WpfDialogSample.Result` ?

Comment: @AlexD Это фича C# 6, "using static". Она позволяет использовать статические методы класов и поля перечислений без указания имени класса. В данном случае в глобальное пространство имён импортируется содержимое `enum Result` из блока кода выше, что позволяет писать `Cancel` вместо `Result.Cancel`.

Comment: VS 2013 ругается на эту строчку. Не могу понять, в чем дело. P. S. `WpfDialogSample` - это, как я понимаю, пространство имен?

Comment: @AlexD У вас старый C#, советую поставить VS2015. Или уберите эту строчку с `using static` и замените `\b(?<!")(Yes|No|Cancel)(?!,)\b` => `Result.$1`.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать это через через `ShowDialog`, но мне кажется более чистым метод с async/await.

Вот простой вариант:

```
public Task<int> ShowMessage()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    var w = new YourWindow();
    w.Closed += (o, args) => tcs.TrySetResult(w.ClickedButtonIndex)
    w.Show();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Для этого, понятно, `YourWindow` должно в публичном свойстве `PressedButtonIndex` запоминать, какая кнопка была нажата. И закрываться по нажатию любой из кнопок. Это делается так:

```
<Button Click="OnButtonClicked" Name="Button1">1</Button>
<Button Click="OnButtonClicked" Name="Button2">2</Button>
```

и в code-behind окна `YourWindow`

```
void OnButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender == Button1)
        ClickedButtonIndex = 1;
    else
        ClickedButtonIndex = 2;
    Close();
}

public int ClickedButtonIndex { get; private set; }
```

Давайте попробуем более изощрённый вариант Для начала, научимся дожидаться нажатия на кнопку:

```
async Task<Button> ClickOnButton(Button b, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Button>();
    RoutedEventHandler handler = (sender, args) => tcs.TrySetResult(b);
    b.Click += handler;
    try
    {
        using (ct.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled()))
            return await tcs.Task;
    }
    finally
    {
        b.Click -= handler;
    }
}

async Task<Button> ClickOnAny(IEnumerable<Button> buttons, CancellationToken ct)
{
    using (var innerCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ct))
    {
        var tasks = buttons.Select(el => ClickOnButton(el, innerCts.Token)).ToList();
        var winningTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        var clickedControl = await winningTask;
        innerCts.Cancel();
        return clickedControl;
    }
}
```

Теперь можно навешивать ожидание на любое окно:

```
public async Task<int> ShowMessage()
{
    var w = new YourWindow();
    w.Show();
    var clickedButton = await ClickOnAny(
           new[] { w.Button1, w.Button2 }, CancellationToken.None);
    w.Close();
    return clickedButton == w.Button1 ? 1 : 2;
}
```

При таком подходе окно не обязано «сотрудничать».

И в заключение стандартный (на мой вкус, устаревший) вариант с `ShowDialog`:

```
int ShowMessage()
{
    var dw = new YourWindow();
    var result = dw.ShowDialog();
    if (result == true)
        return dw.ClickedButtonIndex;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Для этого в `YourWindow` должен быть такой code-behind:

```
void OnButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender == Button1)
        ClickedButtonIndex = 1;
    else
        ClickedButtonIndex = 2;
    DialogResult = true;
}

public int ClickedButtonIndex { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Какие преимущества у сложного способа-то?

Comment: @Discord: Например, это не блокирующий вызов. А значит, мы можем дожидаться этого и ещё чего-то параллельно. Кроме того, мы можем навесить cancellation.

Comment: @Discord: Ага, `ShowPopup` у вас делает то же самое. Ну тогда можно дожидаться клика на чём угодно, даже если это самое оно не сотрудничает. Таким образом, можно строить бизнес-логику не на event-oriented flow, а на Task-based. Что само по себе приятно и намного более прозрачно для сложных flow.

Comment: Приведите конкретный сценарий, когда это нужно. Что значит "окно не сотрудничает"?

Comment: @Discord: Ну, например, окно вам дано сверху, и его код нельзя менять. То есть оно категорически не согласно делать `Close` по нажатию кнопки. Или например оно вовсе не должно закрываться по нажатию этой самой кнопки, а вы хотите просто выяснить, на какую из них нажал юзер. Можно это закодировать подпиской на ивенты и отпиской от них, но получится спагетти.

Comment: @Discord: Идея в том, чтобы UI-события превратить в Task'и, а ими-то можно манипулировать намного понятнее для программиста. Особенно, повторюсь, при сложном флоу, когда нужно, к примеру, подождать, пока юзер нажмёт на одну кнопку из двух, потом добавить в окно фотографию и показать третью и снова дождаться, пока он нажмёт, и всё это flow прервать по нажатию cancel.

Comment: Я, конечно, понимаю, что вы изголодались по сложным вопросам, но показывать этот хардкор с тасками, когда ОП пытается разобраться с получением результата из диалога — это жестоко. :) Вы б ещё Rx, Dataflow и далее по списку понакрутили.

Comment: @Discord: Ну это да :) Поэтому я всё же дал в конце простой вариант, и плюсанул ваш ответ :-D Насчёт Rx надо подумать, как его получше сюда прикрутить.

Comment: @Discord: А ещё я не любитель блокирующих функций, которые запускают вложенный фрейм диспетчера (наподобие ShowDialog). На мой вкус это poor man's Task. Впрочем, это уже вкусовщина.