# Для каких целей нужен метод PushFrame

Tags: c#, wpf

Я наткнулся на метод `PushFrame` у класса `Dispatcher`. Бегло посмотрел реализацию и прочитал про него в документации. Вот упрощенная версия этого метода.

```
public void PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
{
    // Stuff
    _frameDepth++;
    while(frame.Continue)
    {
        // Getting and dispatching messages
    }
   _frameDepth--;
   // Stuff
}
```

Я понимаю что метод просто создает и обрабатывает новый цикл сообщений. Но я не могу понять, какие именно цели такой подход может достигать? Разве одного цикла недостаточно? Более я того, я скольнен полагать, что использование еще одного вложенного цикла может вести к довольно неочевидным ошибкам

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хороший вопрос.

Коротко — вы не должны им пользоваться в обычном случае, этот метод — внутренний метод инфраструктуры.

Ситуации, в которых нужно было бы использование `PushFrame` — блокирующие методы наподобие [`ShowDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) (в самом `ShowDialog` [тоже используется `PushFrame`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs,5777)). В них вам нужно на время работы блокирующей функции не прекращать обработку цикла сообщений, и для этодо при помощи `PushFrame` создаётся вложенный цикл.

В современном C# использование блокирующих методов считается неидиоматичным. Правильным дизайном с позиций сегодняшнего дня было бы использование `async`-варианта. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/449911/10105) есть примеры такого дизайна с кодом.

Comment: Да, действительно. Для модальных окон самое оно