# Команда кнопки "ОК" дочернего окна, закрывающего его. MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Создание и показ дочернего окна из MainViewModel:

```
    public ICommand OpenWindow_AddNewBid_Command => new RelayCommand<object>(p => OpenWindow_AddNewBid());
    private void OpenWindow_AddNewBid()
    {            
        var wnd = new AddNewBidWindow();           
        if (wnd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            AddNewBidViewModel vm = (AddNewBidViewModel)wnd.DataContext;
            AddNewBidToCollection(vm.CreatedBid);
        }
    }
```

В ViewModel дочернего окна есть команда, которая привязана к кнопке OK.

```
    public ICommand AddNewBidCommand => new RelayCommand<object>(p => AddNewBid(),
                                                                 p => IsValid);
```

XAML:

```
<Button Command="{Binding AddNewBidCommand}" IsDefault="True">ОК</Button>
```

Не могу понять, как сделать, что бы выполнилась команда привязанная к кнопке и окно закрылось?

Comment: Чем не устраивает простой вариант - вызвать метод `Close` у окна?

Comment: из VM? Она же ничего не знает об окне?

Comment: Как то вы сложно выражаетесь. Ваш вопрос должен звучать проще. Что-то вроде "как в рамках MVVM принято закрывать окно?".

Comment: Можно передать окно параметром в команду. Можно - найти в вм связанные окна и закрыть их все. Идеальных вариантов я тут не видел.

Comment: Где-то было на моей памяти несколько похожих вопросов.

Comment: Вот: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/525998/10105 и http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/449911/10105

Comment: Ну и если мы говорим о MVVM-закрытии окна, то имеет смысл говорить и о MVVM-создании окна. В вопросе окно создаётся в VM-коде.

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой вариант, не нарушающий принципы MVVM.

**View**:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var vm = new MainViewModel();
        this.DataContext = vm;
        vm.CloseHandler += (sender, args) => this.Close();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**:

```
public class MainViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public EventHandler CloseHandler;

    public ICommand AddNewBidCommand => new RelayCommand(action =>
    {
        // ...

        var handler = CloseHandler;
        if (handler != null) handler.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

    }, canExecute => true);

}
```

Вариант с передачей экземпляра окна в команду через `CommandParameter` возможен, но будет нарушать принципы MVVM.

Comment: Какой принцип будет нарушать передача окна через параметр?

Comment: @maxwell появляется зависимость VM от конкретного View. Таким образом теряется весь смысл использования этого паттерна. Вью-модель должна "общаться" с представлением только посредством механизма привязки данных (bindings)

Comment: @Nikita, если окно будет реализовывать интерфейс IClosable, то при передаче окна через параметр ничего не нарушится)

Answer (score 3):

Изящный вариант закрытия окна из VM в духе MVVM (декларативный и через биндинги)

Вспомогательный класс

```
public static class DialogCloser
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DialogResultProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "DialogResult",
            typeof (bool?),
            typeof (DialogCloser),
            new PropertyMetadata(DialogResultChanged));

    private static void DialogResultChanged(
        DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = d as Window;
        if (window != null)
        {
            window.DialogResult = e.NewValue as bool?;
            if (window.DialogResult != null)
                window.Close();
        }
    }

    public static void SetDialogResult(Window target, bool? value)
    {
        target.SetValue(DialogResultProperty, value);
    }
}
```

VM

```
class MyViewModel
{
   
   private bool? _dialogResult;

   public bool? DialogResult
    {
        get { return _dialogResult; }
        protected set
        {
            _dialogResult = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DialogResult");
        }
    }

    public ICommand OkCommand {get;}=new RelayCommand(Save);

    private void Save()
    {
        ....
        DialogResult = true;
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window ...DialogCloser.DialogResult="{Binding DialogResult}" .../>
```

При выставлении у VM DialogResult=true/false форма закроется и у нее будет установлен DialogResult, так что проверка результата будет работать

```
if(view.ShowDialog()==true)..
```

upd:
Если нужно при нажатии кнопки закрытия окна нужно не закрывать сразу, а в `OnClosing` вызвать вьюмодель с просьбой "останови все, а я подожду" и эта вьюмодель в итоге установит `DialogResult=true`, то будет ошибка вида "во время закрытия окна нельзя изменить Visibility". Решается `await Task.Yield();` в `OnClosing`