# Закрыть окно WPF с MVVM

Tags: wpf, windows, xaml, mvvm, binding

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли закрыть окно через xaml по привязки к свойстку во ViewModel. То есть, например, есть окно которое должно автоматически закрываться (скрываться) после выполнения логики.

Comment: Самое простое - сделайте интерфейс с действием закрытия (например `public interface IClosable { Action Close(); }`), унаследуйтесь от него в `MainViewModel` (или кто у вас там главный для окна), ну а в окне, по событию `Loaded` сделайте чет по типу `if (DataContext is IClosable cl) { cl.Close += () => { ... }; }`, прописав вместо `...` логику закрытия. Все, теперь можете в VM спокойно вызывать `Close?.Invoke();` и окно закроется. Но в этом способе есть ряд тонкостей, ну и если вам нужна полноценная работа с окнами (открыть, закрыть, диалог), то лучше написать свой менеджер окон.

Comment: Ну если совсем декларативно, то [такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648702/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d0%9a-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-mvvm-wpf/648789#648789).