# SelectedItem C# WPF вместо SelectionChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, события

Что лучше использовать? Вместо SelectionChanged использовать SelectedItem

```
private Game _SelectedItem;
public Game SelectedItem
{
    get { return _SelectedItem; }
    set { _SelectedItem = value; OnPropertyChanged(); System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(((Game)value).Creator); }
}
```

или все таки так

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Games}" Background="#FF292D32" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction
                Command="{Binding ItemChanged}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: `Что лучше использовать?` - что значит лучше?

Comment: Ну наверно что правильней для паттерна MVVM использовать. И вообще правильно ли вызывать метод в сеттере свойства

Comment: для паттерна MVVM использовать привязки и команды - это норм (другое дело, что вы могли привязаться гораздо проще и без команды). Вызывать в сеттере `OnPropertyChanged()` - это норм. Вызывать во вьюмодели какие то UI вещи типа диалогового окна - это не норм и вообще неправильно.

Comment: 1) А как проще сделать (мне просто нужно чтоб при смене Item`а вызывался метод куда передавался бы ну допустим Title этого айтема)
2) Я в курсе что в сеттере OnPropertyChanged() вызывать это норм. А другие методы?
3) А как вызывать диалоговое окно по правилам mvvm?

Comment: 1) Использовать биндинг к свойству, что то типа `<ListBox .... SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" .... `  2) Сеттеры и геттеры по всем рекомендациям должны быть максимально простыми, чем проще - тем лучше. Если вы начнете писать лапшу логики в сеттерах, получите неподдерживаемую кашу в коде 3) Писать спец класс для показа окон, вызывать из модели этот класс

Comment: 1) Так то в 1 варианте у меня так и работает привязка только у меня возник вопрос правильно ли будет если я в сеттер внесу вызов метода Test(((Game)value).Title); 3) а можно ссылку на пример такого класса пожалуйста

Comment: 1) Метода `Test` нет нигде в вашем вопросе, потому ответить не это нечего 3) [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/727749/179763), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/526028/179763), [три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/449911/179763)

Comment: Да боже вопрос простой правильно ли будет в сеттере SelectedItem вызвал вместо OnPropertyChanged() еще какой либо метод НАПРИМЕР Test(); p.s я не верю в то что вы не догадались что это для примера я написал

Comment: так я на это уже ответил же `Сеттеры и геттеры по всем рекомендациям должны быть максимально простыми, чем проще - тем лучше. Если вы начнете писать лапшу логики в сеттерах, получите неподдерживаемую кашу в коде`

Comment: Вообщем понял! Нормально если я так сделаю каши поидее не будет

Comment: MVVM - это паттерн, подход, он описывает только основную концепцию, а не детали. Вызывать или нет в сеттерах что то - это детали, паттерну до этого дела нет, потому вам никто не запрещает вызывать, но есть просто рекомендация делать сеттеры/геттеры попроще. От одного вызова простого метода ничего страшного не случится. Но от портянки логики будут проблемы, особенно с тестированием и асинхронностью

Comment: Вот последний вопрос в 1 примере который вы скинули. (спасибо за него на многие вопросы нашел ответ) но я не понял 1 момента где у него в коде команда ExitCommand? Весь код перешарил так и не нашел. Но приложение на ctrl+x закрывается.

Comment: И зачем там нужны какие-то сервисы?